# Is it possible to place vertical scroll bar of ace editor to the left?

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar, ace-editor

I want the scroll bar of ace editor be shown on the left instead of the right.

Is it possible, and how can a archive that?

Thanks.

---

I have searched and checked the documentation, but not found related topics. I also try to handle this in my css: But it seems that the position is calculated by javascript, which means it is hard to handle by css.

I do not want to modify library codes.

Comment: how would that interact with the gutter? do you want to place scrollbar before or after the gutter?

Comment: @auser scrollbar is the most left thing, gutter should be placed on the right side of scroll bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `.ace_scrollbar.ace_scrollbar-v { left: 0 }` to place scrollbar over the gutter, but to make it work properly you'll have to change [virtual_renderer.js#L414](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.2.6/lib/ace/virtual_renderer.js#L414), and several other places, so i'd say it is not possible without modifying the library.
Why do you want to put scrollbar on the left side?

Comment: I want an editor for multiple language. And when markdown is chosen, I want the scrollbar shown on left side, and show preview on right side. something like `<div style="overflow: auto; direction: rtl; height: 100%;">`